# Passport Nodejs failed to verify assertion

Tags: node.js, oauth, passport.js, steam

```
InternalOpenIDError: Failed to verify assertion
at /var/nodejs/Website/node_modules/passport-openid/lib/passport-openid/strategy.js:184:36
at /var/nodejs/Website/node_modules/openid/openid.js:927:12
at /var/nodejs/Website/node_modules/openid/openid.js:1051:16
at /var/nodejs/Website/node_modules/openid/openid.js:1169:16
at Request._callback (/var/nodejs/Website/node_modules/openid/openid.js:190:7)
at Request.self.callback (/var/nodejs/Website/node_modules/request/request.js:198:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:172:7)
at Request.<anonymous> (/var/nodejs/Website/node_modules/request/request.js:1035:10)
at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
GET /auth/steam/callback?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Flogin&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Fid%2F76561198197967283&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Fid%2F76561198197967283&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fcsgomayhem.com%2Fauth%2Fsteam%2Fcallback&openid.response_nonce=2015-11-25T18%3A40%3A44ZOdgvGQXoVnz9LWfko54I371tMOM%3D&openid.assoc_handle=1234567890&openid.signed=signed%2Cop_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle&openid.sig=L5jXiwo2S4mVe0r%2BkcpU%2Bj%2BaEEU%3D 500 665ms - 708b
```

I've had my code working for several weeks now in my windows dev environment but now trying to run it on an Ubuntu 14.04 prod machine I am presented with this error when authenticating someone through Steam. I have no idea what the error means and Googling and searching on here hasn't yielded any results. I can provide the relevant code if you tell me what I'm looking for or if this is an easy fix please let me know.

All help would be greatly appreciated, regards.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by downgrading my version of passport as if appeared to be incompatible with passport-steam. I see some examples for authentication on the github of passport-steam if you ever need if for just authenticating users but not getting their details.